# how to generate .bak file from my ips .net core project?

Tags: c#, sql, database, asp.net-core, ssms

I have created a project using .NET core and now I want to generate a database .Bak file using, and I just don't know how or if it's even possible or not.

I just want some other opinions and insights.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-a-full-database-backup-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#TsqlProcedure)? If you know how to run raw SQL queries from .NET it seems like this is a good path forward

Comment: `BACKUP DATABASE ... TO DISK = N'Somefile.bak'`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use .NET 7 with linqTodb

here the code

```
 
public virtual async Task BackupDatabaseAsync(string fileName)
{
    using var currentConnection = CreateDataConnection();
    var commandText = $"BACKUP DATABASE [{currentConnection.Connection.Database}] TO DISK = '{fileName}' WITH FORMAT";
    await currentConnection.ExecuteAsync(commandText);
}

protected virtual DataConnection CreateDataConnection(IDataProvider dataProvider)
{
    if (dataProvider is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataProvider));

    var dataConnection = new DataConnection(dataProvider, CreateDbConnection(), GetMappingSchema())
    {
        CommandTimeout = DataSettingsManager.GetSqlCommandTimeout()
    };

    return dataConnection;
}
```